# Complex selecting of specific inputs generated by for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm trying to select some specific inputs in a list of inputs generated by a `for-loop`, inside some divs also generated by `for-loop`. That means that the selecting process is a bit messy and difficult, because the `ids` are dynamic.

So, here is a sample of what I have, every id is generated by a `for-loop`:

```
<div id="block0">
    <input id="special0-0" class="block"></input>
    <input id="special0-1" class="block"></input>
    <input id="special0-2" class="block"></input>
    <input id="special0-3" class="block"></input>
</div>
<div id="block1">
    <input id="special1-0" class="block"></input>
    <input id="special1-1" class="block"></input>
    <input id="special1-2" class="block"></input>
    <input id="special1-3" class="block"></input>
</div>
<div id="item0">
    <input id="special0-0"></input>
    <input id="special0-1"></input>
    <input id="special0-2"></input>
    <input id="special0-3"></input>
</div>
<div id="item1">
    <input id="special1-0"></input>
    <input id="special1-1"></input>
    <input id="special1-2"></input>
    <input id="special1-3"></input>
</div>
```

I want to select the inputs with `id="special0-2` **AND** `id="special1-2"` **BUT NOT** the ones which have `class="block"`.

I've tried several possibilities, including these two that should work to me:

```
var item2 = $("div[id|='item'] > input[id$='-2']");

var item2 = $("input[id|='special'][id$='-2'][class!='block']");
```

The problem is, for each option, `console.log(item2)` returns `0` and I can't apply the javascript changes I planned on them after. Thanks for your ideas :)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdns1p2z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be it:

```
$('[id^="item"]').children('[id$="-2"]:not(.block)'); // full
$('[id^="item"] > [id$="-2"]:not(.block)'); // short
```

First select the divs with the id's that start with 'item', in those find those with the id ending with '-2'.

I suggest you give the root items a class. If you always want the 3rd one, combined it would be:

```
$('.classname').children('div:nth-child(3)'); // full
$('.classname > div:nth-child(3)'); // short
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the JSFiddle, and none of your 4 options seem to work, I still see `0` in the logs: http://jsfiddle.net/rdns1p2z/4

Comment: Nevermind. For some reason, it returns 0 in the JSFiddle, but your solution #1 works perfectly in my real code. Thank you! :)

Comment: wrap the code with $(document).ready. It will work. By the time you execute the code, dom is not ready. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdns1p2z/5/